# Mat-select multiple rtl direction display reverse selected items text

Tags: angular, angular-material, right-to-left

I Use `Mat-select` with `multiple` option

I order my data with custom order pipe.

I set the `direction` to `rtl` ,

the mat-select display the items in the correct order, but the inner text that display the selected items appears backwards.

**For example :**

The display text in the input :

```
ג,ב,א
```

instead of

```
א,ב,ג
```

[My Mat Select Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-mat-select-rvnt8r?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `mat-select-trigger` inside your `mat-select`

and display the value of the selected their.

your code would look like:

```
  <mat-select name="subjectCtrl"
                    multiple
                    #subjectCtrl='ngModel'
                    required
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedSubjectsList">
          <mat-select-trigger>
              selectedText
          </mat-select-trigger>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let subject of subjectList"
                      [value]="subject.Code">
            {{subject.Desc}}
          </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the CSS class:

```
.mat-option {
  text-align: left!important;
}
```

To allow a better display. [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-mat-select-multiple-rtl-direction-display-reverse)

DEMO:

[image]

Comment: No, this was not the problem, I ask about the selected items display in the textbox backwards

Answer (score 2):

here is a css fix for hebrew/rtl

```
/*mat select rtl*/
.mat-form-field-label, .mat-select-value{text-align: right}
.mat-option { direction: rtl; }
.mat-option-text {margin-right: 10px;text-align: right; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add style to `.mat-form-field{text-align: right}` in you component.css

```
.mat-form-field {
  text-align: right
}
```

If dont work styles you can do like this:

```
.mat-form-field {
  text-align: right!important
}
```

or

```
   /deep/.mat-form-field {
      text-align: right
    }
```

Comment: It is what you need? or am i not understand you?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-mat-select-rru4yw?file=app/app.component.css

Comment: No, this was not the problem, I ask about the selected items display in the textbox backwards